# Mouse and keyboard not working in Ubuntu 14.04 login screen

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, mouse

I update Linux to 14.04 and now then the mouse and keyboard doesn't work in login screen. I try reinstallin grub from a live usb, but it still not working. I would really appreciate your help.

Ivana